How do I make an about:blank cloak work automatically similiar to Interstellars?
I already got an about; blank cloak, but you have to click it for it to work, is there any way to cloak the site right as you open it?
The script I used was
<button onclick="openGame()">about:blank cloak</button>
    <script>
        function openGame() {
    var win = window.open()
    var url = "https://learnmathswithme.weebly.com"
    var iframe = win.document.createElement('iframe')
    iframe.style.width = "100%";
    iframe.style.height = "100%";
    iframe.style.border = "none";
    iframe.src = url
    win.document.body.appendChild(iframe)
    }
    </script>

which I found off the internet (since I'm not a coder), is there a change I can make to cloak the site automatically?

What exactly is an "about:blank cloak"?
